# Firebase Firestone rules with collection group ressource data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to **delete all students** in my Firestore database, to do this I used **collection group** but I had a problem with rules: I can't achieve to authorize read, delete & update permissions.

#### Code

Here is the dart code in Flutter to retrieve all students in any nested collections AND delete them:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collectionGroup('students')
  .where('studentId', isEqualTo: studentId)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) async {
    for (var snapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
      await snapshot.reference.delete();
    }
  }
});
```

#### Rules

The rules I used but doesn't work because It seems `resource.data.classId` can't be accessed...

```js
function isClassBelongToUser(classId) {
  return classId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.classIds
}

match /{path=**}/students/{id} {
  allow read, delete, update: if isSignedIn() && isClassBelongToUser(resource.data.classId); // TODO: resource.data.classId seems to not work
}
```

#### My database

classes / *CLASS_ID* / (students: *collection*, name: *string*, ...)

users / *USER_ID* / (classIds: *array*, firstName: *string*, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security rules don't filter data, but instead merely ensure that the operation you perform is authorized. See the documentation on [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).

Since your `isClassBelongToUser` check requires that the user exists in the `classIds` of a specific document, your query must ensure this condition is satisfied too. Since Firestore can only filter on values in the documents it returns, such a condition is unfortunately not possible.

You will have to adapt your data model to allow the use-case, for example by replicating the necessary information into the `students` document(s).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but we can't access to students data into the ```match /{path=**}/students/{id}``` filter rules ?

Comment: That is correct: queries can only check values in the documents they return, not in other documents. And as far as I can see, your `isBelongTo` checks in a collection `users`, while you are querying the `students` collection(s).